# response.Headers.ElementAt missing?

Tags: header, response

I created an interface to consume a webservice in VB.NET using Restsharp. Now I am repogramming it in C#.NET.

I would like to show the information from the headers of te response to the request however as in VB.NET I can enumerate through bij stating `response.headers(index)` I should use .ElementAt in C#.

ElementAt does not show. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this. `response.headers[index]`

Comment: Great! Works like a charm: next step is to get it in a string to create output on screen. for (int i = 0; i < (response.Headers.Count - 1); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers[i]);
            } - Doesn't like .ToString however.

Comment: Soveld .ToString should read .ToString() Thanks!